# Ubuntu Linux Keepass2 Google Drive Sync Plugin Error

Tags: linux, keepass, mono-framework

I'm using KeePass2 with Google Drive Sync for quite some time now on Windows and Android without anny issues.

Now I installed KeePass on Ubuntu 16.04 (tried Keepass 2.32 and 2.35 from PPA, no difference) and GoogleSyncPlugin 2.?? and newest 3.0.1.

With 2.?? version of the Plugin, I encountered an Error with logger. With 3.0.1 I now get a different porblem "The plugin cannot be loaded. A newer .NET Framework is required".

I'm sure, the problem is with Mono in both cases, but I have no idea how to solve it.

Comment: I don't know if you found this. Maybe will be useful: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/245123/keepass2-and-google-sync-plugin/254115#254115

Answer (score 0):

Here is a discussion of KeePass with plugins on Ubuntu and either browser integration in general and that is more current: "KeePass and Ubuntu 20.04 Setup (with Chrome, Firefox)?" https://askubuntu.com/questions/1228389/keepass-and-ubuntu-20-04-setup-with-chrome-firefox